# Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset. python-binance module

Tags: python, binance

I coded a trading bot with python-binance module the bot takes coin name from a message than open a position like
takes-message > opens long position to the coin in the message > sets a limit sell order for the position

the bot can do first two but when it tries to do last one it gives the error `"Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset." I have looked up on the internet for solution and I have tried to set sellPrice with this code

```
float(str(price).split('.')[0] + "." + str(price).split('.')[1][0:5])+(price*0.3/100)
```

I take first part of code from internet which is  `float(str(price).split('.')[0] + "." + str(price).split('.')[1][0:5])`

and added the part of setting the sellPrice %0.3 above from the price I buy

this is my code

```
coinName = "ONEUSDT"
print(coinName)
symbol = coinName
amount = "1"
leverage = "20"
self.client.futures_change_leverage(symbol=symbol, leverage=leverage)
price=float(self.client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=symbol)["price"])
print(price)
amount = float(amount)
leverage = float(leverage)
quantity =(amount*leverage)/price
quantity = int(quantity)
self.client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol,side="BUY",type="MARKET",quantity=quantity)
time.sleep(3)
self.client.futures_create_order(symbol=symbol,side="SELL",type="LIMIT",price =float(str(price).split('.')[0] + "." + str(price).split('.')[1][0:5])+(price*0.3/100),quantity=quantity,timeInForce="GTC")
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for tick_size, which will show you how many decimal places to round the price to. There is a helper module you can import for rounding and we can run our tick size and our price into that. Those docs can be seen here:

[Binance Order Filters](https://sammchardy.github.io/binance-order-filters/)

We need to make sure to import the helper function from the helper module at the top of app.py. Then insert the following function in the body of your script. Assuming your internet message gives us a price properly, then `cost` will be the variable we can insert into our final order as the rounded price. I just ran this in my interpreter and it works with substituted values:

```
from binance.helpers import round_step_size # add at top

cost = float(str(price).split('.')[0] + "." + str(price).split('.')[1][0:5])+(price*0.3/100)

data = self.client.futures_exchange_info() # request data
info = data['symbols'] # pull list of symbols
for x in range(len(info)): # find length of list and run loop
    if info[x]['symbol'] == symbol: # until we find our coin
        a = info[x]["filters"][0]['tickSize'] # break into filters pulling tick size
        cost = round_step_size(cost, float(a)) # convert tick size from string to float, insert in helper func with cost
        print(cost) # run into order parameter as price=cost
```

Cheers and best of luck with your coding and trading!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add decimal places to avoid this error
eg:
var1 = 0.5  # this causes the error

FIX
var1 = 0.5000  # fix the error

Answer (score 0):

To solve the precision issue in Python, it is necessary to ensure that the asset does not have decimals. One way to do this is by using the math.floor() function. This will round the number down to the nearest integer, effectively removing any decimal places.